# $E[X]< (\sum_{n=0}^\infty P[X>n]< E[X]+1$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If X takes only non-negative integer values then I figured out 
$$E[X]= (\sum_{n=0}^\infty P[X>n]$$

but I'm having hard time proving

$$ E[X]⩽ (\sum_{n=0}^\infty P[X>n] ⩽ E[X]+1$$ for any non-negative random variable X

I feel like this statement is contradicting the first part of the question. Can someone show me how?

Comment: It is not contradicting the first part of the question if we replace the first $\lt$ by $\leqslant$.

Comment: actually it is ⩽. thanks for pointing it out. Can you help me prove that statement?

Comment: I don't understand, isn't it trivial once you got the equality between $E[X]$ and $\sum_n P(X\gt n)$? Or you are asking for a direct method?

Comment: Well i just proved E[x]=P(x>n)... but i cant prove the other part.

Comment: @user139575 If you've shown $a=b$ then automatically $a\leq b\leq a+1$

Comment: but the second part is for any non-negative random variable X whereas the first part is for only non-negative integer values.

Answer (score 1):

Since the first part is for integer-valued variables, while in the second part $X$ is not integer valued, you should do some rounding. Up or down? The direction of inequality suggests rounding up. So, let $Y=\lceil X\rceil$. Clearly, $X\le Y\le X+1$. Also, 
$$E[Y]= \sum_{n=0}^\infty P[Y>n]$$
by the first part. It remains to observe that  $Y>n$ if and only $X>n$.